# Sorting an array of objects using natural order

Tags: arrays, sorting

I have a data file of 10000 lines with the following on each line "lastName, firstName middleName  social security" I want to sort this using the comparable interface where the comparison is based on the name (last, first middle); if the last, first and middle names are the same, then use the social security as a secondary sort field for that record.
My problem is I am reading each name into a separate array and hence I am not able to perform the above task. Below is a sample of how I am reading the file and my sort method.

{
      while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())

```
    {
        //Each String in the line of the data file is read into an array
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner (fileScanner.nextLine());

        lastName [i] = lineScanner.next();
        firstName [i] = lineScanner.next();
        middleName [i] = lineScanner.next();
        id [i] = lineScanner.next(); 
        lastName[i] = lastName[i].substring(0, lastName[i].indexOf(','));
                    i++
  }

                    Sorts.selectionSort(lastName, firstName, middleName, id);
```

}

//sort method

```
public static void selectionSort (Object [] x, Object [] y, Object [] z, Object [] a)
{


    // Make [0 ... i] sorted and <= x [i + 1]  ...x [x.length -1]:
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length -1; i++) 
         {

        int pos = i;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < x.length; k++)
            if (((Comparable)x [k]).compareTo(x [pos]) < 0)

                pos = k;
            swap (x, i, pos);
            System.out.println(x[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < y.length -1; j++)
    {
        int pos2 = j;
        for (int k = j + 1; k < y.length; k++)
            if (((Comparable)y [k]).compareTo(y [pos2]) < 0)

                pos2 = k;
            swap (y, j, pos2);
            System.out.println(y[j]);

    }
    for (int m = 0; m < z.length -1; m++)
    {
        int pos3 = m;
        for (int k = m + 1; k < y.length; k++)
            if (((Comparable)z [k]).compareTo(z [pos3]) < 0)

                pos3 = m;
            swap (y, m, pos3);
            //System.out.println(z[m]);

    }

    for (int l = 0; l < a.length -1; l++)
    {
        int pos4 = l;
        for (int k = l + 1; k < y.length; k++)
            if (((Comparable)a [k]).compareTo(a [pos4]) < 0)

                pos4 = l;
            swap (y, l, pos4);
            System.out.println(a[l]);

    }   


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Person class with first name, last name, and social security number and when reading the input, create instances of the Person class and put them in an ArrayList. Then you don't have to worry about having multiple arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You are using java, so stop using C-like structures.  Define an object with properties firstName, lastName, middleName, ssn.  Create a new object for each individual and store it in a List (maybe a LinkedList or an ArrayList).

Override the equals and hashcode methods on your object.

Use Collections.sort() to sort the list.